# creating multidimensional array with index based on row value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have the following table in my mysql database with events with start and end TIME datatype:

```
start_time  end_time    day 
08:00:00    16:00:00    1
08:00:00    16:00:00    1
08:00:00    16:00:00    4
08:00:00    16:00:00    5
```

I want to create a multidimensional array with this where each day have it's start_time and end_time in an array, like this;

```
array:3 [
    1 => array:2 [
        0 => array:2 [
            0 => "08:00"
            1 => "16:00"
        ]
        1 => array:2 [
            0 => "08:00"
            1 => "16:00"
        ]
    ]
    4 => array:1 [
        0 => array:2 [
            0 => "08:00"
            1 => "16:00"
        ]
    ]
    5 => array:1 [
        0 => array:2 [
            0 => "08:00"
            1 => "16:00"
        ]
    ]
]
```

I have a variable with all events in which i could foreach to go through.

Is this doable or do I need to use pivot tables to keep these two values seperated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through your fetched rows and use the `day` as the key and dynamically add an element `[]` and assign the times as an array:

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $result[$row['day']][] = array($row['start_time'],
                                   $row['end_time']);
}
```

Or do it when fetching from the DB:

```
while($row = /* fetch_function() */) {
    $result[$row['day']][] = array($row['start_time'],
                                   $row['end_time']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
 $records = array(
    array(
        'start_time' => '00:11:22',
        'end_time'   => '11:22:33',
        'day' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'start_time' => '20:11:22',
        'end_time'   => '21:22:33',
        'day' => 2
    ),
    array(
        'start_time' => '10:11:22',
        'end_time'   => '11:22:33',
        'day' => 1
    )

); // Your actual data would replace this of course

 $sorted = array();
 foreach($records as $record){
     // Group by day
     $sorted[$record['day']][] = $record;
 }


 // Group again
 $results = array();
 foreach($sorted as $day => $records){
     foreach($records as $record){
        $results[$day][] = 
        array($record['start_time'],$record['end_time']);   
     }

 }

 var_dump($results);
```